# Get properties that are of type ICollection<BaseEntity>

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am struggling to get all properties of a class which is a `ICollection<BaseEntity>`.

Example Entities:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Post : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public Post MyPost { get; set; }
}
```

I can get the properties which is of a class derived from BaseEntity by using:

```
var baseEntProps = properties.Where(p => typeof(BaseEntity).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType));
```

How can i do the same for the ICollection? I've tried

```
var p2 = properties.Where(p => typeof (ICollection<BaseEntity>).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType));
```

but that does not give the any result. I can use the `ICollection<Post>` instad of `ICollection<BaseEntity>` but that deflects the purpose of what I am trying to do.

```
var p2 = properties.Where(p => typeof (ICollection<Post>).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty ugly but can do this:

```
var baseEntProps = properties
.Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
            p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>) &&
            typeof(BaseEntity).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]));
```